# Is it possible to run PHP files that are outside of Virtualbox instance?

Tags: php, virtualbox, puppet, vagrant

I use Vagrant and Puppet to recreate my live VPS and I'd like to test my PHP files locally against that. I have osx so during development I use the apache server there, but I'd like to use the same php files on the virtualbox rather than copy them over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Share the directory over network (NFS, SAMBA, whatever) and mount it on the VirtualBox.

Comment: thanks. It's so easy to do via Vagrant http://vagrantup.com/v1/docs/config/vm/share_folder.html